# Terminal's bin/bash not responding

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell

I have Googled through several instances of this issue but cannot get Terminal to open up with bash. I restarted the program, the computer and even logged in through another Administrator account but this did not solve the issue. (Note: I'm the only user. I created the alternate for this purpose just in case it would respond). I assume it might have something to do with the fact that the bash executable is zero bytes in size and was accessed today. I don't know how but perhaps I altered it?

Here is a screenshot with the relevant windows:
[image]

The bash file exists where it should, the Terminal startup settings are set to open with /bin/bash, and the text on what "used to be" my Terminal is as follows:

```
[Command not found: /bin/bash]

[Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I added your image for you and fixed your grammar. I had to upload the image to a new site because dropbox image was "not supported" in superuser. GRAMMAR NOTE: "I Googled" and "I restarted" are already past tense. You did the correct thing when you wrote "I created". "I've Googled" is wrong because it is the same as "I have Googled", which is actually redundant, since "Googled" is past tense and already implies that it was done in the past. Also, "have" is simply the inappropriate tense for this context. Hope that helps! :) Also remember to wrap code using the CODE tags.

Comment: This might be more appropriate on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In case someone runs into this post in the future -- I was able to fix this issue by making a copy of the bash executable at <code>/usr/local/bin/</code> and moving it moving it to <code>/bin/</code>

Comment: In case someone runs into this post in the future -- I was able to fix this issue by making a copy of the bash executable at `/usr/local/bin/` and moving it moving it to `/bin/`

Comment: Be aware that `/usr/local/bin/bash` was probably a new version than the version 3.2 that ships as `/bin/bash`, so there is a slight chance of some compatibility issues for scripts that assume behavior specific to `bash` 3.2. This should not be a problem for system scripts, as I think the different versions of `bash` behave identically when invoked as `/bin/sh`.

Comment: You could always step up to zsh ;)